# Difficulties with Concatination while using MMult for a non cte range in Selection.Formula VBA

Tags: vba

As you might suspect the temp1, temp2 variables change if the user of the programm changes values of cells in Excel, so the range is not constant and function of these variables.

Please Help me as I do not know where the error ( a type mismatch error ) is:

```
Range(Cells(9, 7 + 2 * temp2 + 1), Cells(8 + temp2, 7 + 2 * temp2 + 1)).Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
     "=MMULT(" & Range(Cells(9, 7 + temp2), Cells(8 + temp2, 7 + 2 * temp2 - 1)) & ",MMULT(TRANSPOSE(" & Range(Cells(9, 6), Cells(9 + temp1, 5 + temp2)) & ")," & Range(Cells(9, 3), Cells(9 + temp1, 3)) & "))"
```

Comment: Could you explain more about what your problem is? What error do you get?

Comment: @ Sebastian the error was an error while concatinating I thought it was clear. My bad ! but I have the answer now so thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any clue in the question as to what error you are getting, and on which line, I will take a stab in the dark and suggest you are getting an error trying to concatenate a two-dimensional array into a `String`.

I **think** you are trying to do:

```
Range(Cells(9, 7 + 2 * temp2 + 1), Cells(8 + temp2, 7 + 2 * temp2 + 1)).FormulaArray = _
 "=MMULT(" & Range(Cells(9, 7 + temp2), Cells(8 + temp2, 7 + 2 * temp2 - 1)).Address & _
 ",MMULT(TRANSPOSE(" & Range(Cells(9, 6), Cells(9 + temp1, 5 + temp2)).Address & _
 ")," & Range(Cells(9, 3), Cells(9 + temp1, 3)).Address & "))"
```

i.e. use the `.Address` property of your `Range` objects instead of using the (default) `.Value` property.

Comment: You are a KING ! <333333

Thanks heeps !!